# Animating SCNCamera.fStop with property key path doesn't work, only inside implicit SCNTransaction

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit

This code strangely doesn't animate the fStop:

```
cameraNode.camera!.wantsDepthOfField = true
cameraNode.camera!.focusDistance = 2

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fStop")
animation.toValue = 0.5
animation.duration = 0.3
cameraNode.camera!.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

while this one does:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.3
cameraNode.camera!.fStop = 0.5
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Why?

Comment: Both work for me, but the CABasicAnimation gets removed on completion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does this mean that the removal of the animation has some side effects that could determine why it doesn't work for me? I'm not using or storing the animation anywhere else.

Comment: Are you sure its not working, and not just happening so quickly you don’t notice? Try increasing the duration.

Comment: You're right, with a longer duration I can see that it works, but the focal length is reset to the value before the animation as soon as it finishes (or at least that's what it looks like). With `SCNTransaction` after the animation finishes the focal length doesn't jump to the initial value again. Is this documented behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The animation gets removed on completion so the fStop is reset to its initial value. You just need to set the final value on it when you start the animation.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fStop")
animation.fromValue = cameraNode.camera!.fStop
animation.toValue = 0.5
animation.duration = 0.3
cameraNode.camera!.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
cameraNode.camera!.fStop = 0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is the fact that the animation only sets a temporary value documented somewhere?

Comment: It's standard behaviour, CAAnimation's `isRemovedOnCompletion` defaults to true. The animation only affects the `node.presentation` so when the animation is removed the existing node is shown with its initial values.

Comment: Is the fact that CAAnimation only affects `node.presentation` documented?